# How to load Chrome in Puppeteer on Mac?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Why can I not load Chrome in the browser?
I get error:

> The message is Failed to launch the browser process! spawn
> /Applications/GoogleChrome.app ENOENT TROUBLESHOOTING:
> https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

**Node version  v13.12.0**

```
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath:'/Applications/Google\Chrome.app'});
 const page = await browser.newPage();
 await page.goto('https://my.gumtree.com/login', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
 const myButton = await page.$('#google-sign-in-button');
 myButton.click();
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you want to launch puppeteer with already installed chronium, you need to set `executablePath`. So please check the exact path of chronium.

1. browse `chrome://version/` in your chrome.
2. then, you can find `executablePath`.
3. Make sure you wrote the correct path.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath:'your executable Path'});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://my.gumtree.com/login', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
const myButton = await page.$('#google-sign-in-button');
myButton.click();
```

Comment: In my original question  I dragged and dropped the Chrome app from ```Applications``` into terminal and then copied the path . So what is wrong with my path?  See screenshot:  https://imgur.com/ZAojU8V

Answer (score 1):

A more straightforward solution:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'});


executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
```

Hope that helps